# How can define a ponctuation in an enum?

Tags: enum-class

I use Stanford POStagger and I want to define an enum as bellow :

```java
public enum POSType {
    CC("Conjunction"),
    CD("Number"),
        ! ("Punctuation")
         ......
}
```

How can I define a punctuation as an enum variable?